# "Invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase" when installing via Docker

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to install SeaDAS via Docker and this should be the code to enter in the windows PowerShell:

```
docker run -v $HOME/ocssw:/root/ocssw-v $HOME/seadasClientServerShared:/root/seadasClientServerShared -p 6400:6400 -p 6402:6402 -p 6403:6403 -t seadas/ocssw-run:1.0
```

As I try the following problem occurs:

> docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.

How can I fix it? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have a `.yml` file you should provide that. Where exactly did you get that command to run your Docker container?

Comment: In any event the repository must be lowercase.  You have mixed case currently.

Comment: Seems like a lack of spaces in appropriate spaces. Have you tried adding a space before the second `-v` in `-v $HOME/ocssw:/root/ocssw -v $HOME/seadasClientServerShared:/root/seadasClientServerShared`?